# NodeJs call to AWS lambda timeout

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, timeout

I have an AWS lambda that does a very expensive job and sometimes it takes 14m to finish (lambda function has a 15m timeout).

The call to this lambda is done using the **lambda.invoke** method from the aws-sdk with the following settings:

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  maxRetries: 0,
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: (15 * 60 * 1000) + (20 * 1000) // time to wait for a response (lambda timeout + 20s)
  }
});
```

In my nodejs logs I'm able to see:

```
Feb 07 14:29:43.825 invoking lambda
Feb 07 14:45:04.396
Closing job 151218 due to some error: "TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 920000ms"
```

While on my AWS lambda logs I see

```
Feb 07 14:29:44.329 INIT_START Runtime Version: java:8.v14
...
Feb 07 14:40:22.293 REPORT RequestId: xxx Duration: 635736.88 ms
```

As you can see, the invoke + lambda start is consistent, but the lambda ends at 14:40 but the nodejs invoke method is stuck waiting for the response and it times out at 14:45.

I've read the AWS documentation regarding timeouts (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/) and everything seems correct, so I do not know why my invoke method does not return once the lambda finished successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: We are using the latest `aws-sdk` version **2.1310.0**